# Predicate Logic Negation Question

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

What is the equivalent of $\neg (\forall x) (P(x) \vee Q(x))$? Will $P(x) \vee Q(x)$ be negated too? Or is just $\forall x$ negated?

Comment: I've fixed some typos and converted your formulas to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please use MathJax in the future - it makes your posts much easier to read.

Comment: Sometimes $\forall x$ is considered to be just an abbreviation for $\neg\exists x\neg$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\neg (\forall x)(Px \lor Qx)$$

By quantifier negation (QN) rules,
$$(\exists x)\neg(Px \lor Qx)$$

By DeMorgan's Law

$$(\exists x)(\neg Px \land \neg Qx)$$

Answer (score 1):

the Quantifier Negation Law says that:

$$\neg (\forall x ) \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow (\exists x) \neg \varphi(x)$$

for any formula $\varphi(x)$

Hence:

$$\neg (\forall x)(P(x) \lor Q(x)) \Leftrightarrow (\exists x)\neg (P(x) \lor Q(x))$$

Now, you can either leave the statement this way, or you can push the negation further in to get:

$$(\exists x)(\neg P(x) \land \neg Q(x))$$

Which one is it? Your choice!